# detect interface name with perl

Tags: linux, wifi, perl

I want to detect the interface name (can't use udev because of hardware reasons) and do things according to it.

Basically this should be a first check if the wifi device is able to "see" anything.

Code snippet:

```
my $interface = `/sbin/iwconfig 2>&1|grep wlan|cut -d' ' -f1`;
#upping interface
system("ifconfig $interface up");
print "my interface = $interface\n";
```

However it seems there might be a new line stored in $interface" at the time i try to execute the system command. This is the result of execution.

```
sh: line 2: up: command not found
my interface = wlan0
```

Perl Version is an 5.8.3 i am forced to use for this.

How would i store the interface name without the \n (if that is my error)

The Manual told me to use backticks for "system" output.
[PerlFaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why-can%27t-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system%28%29?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) the $interface.